# c++ Why is it legal to call non-const function on member pointer from const function?

Tags: c++, constants, specifications

```
// Example program
using namespace std;

class FOOIMPL {
 public:
  void fooimpl() {}
};

class FOO {
 public:
  void foo() const { fooimpl_->fooimpl(); }
private:
  FOOIMPL* fooimpl_;
};

int main()
{
  FOO foo;
  foo.foo();
}
```

I understand that this conforms to spec because fooimpl_ wasn't declared as `FOOIMPL* const fooimpl_;`

But I wonder, why does the spec allow constant functions to call non-const functions on member variables at all? wouldn't it make sense to make this an error?

Comment: As far as the language is concerned, a pointer is unchanged when the thing it points to changes. This usually isn't true when you consider the total state of an object with a pointer member, but that doesn't matter to the compiler.

Comment: The member is the pointer, not the object the pointer points to.

Comment: But still, the whole point of const correctness is that if I call a const function, it tells me that the object I'm calling it on isn't going to change (and semantically whether this object is assembled of subobjects is an implementation detail). The question linked doesn't answer why the design decision to allow this makes sense, which is what I'm asking here.

Comment: `const`-ness in C++ is not transitive (deep).

Comment: FYI In the TS of Library fundamentals v2 there is [propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) that targets this point.